# React syntax error while compiling component from node_modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, babel-loader

I have below structure and its compiling good.

- **Project**

  - Zoo

    - Src
    - Components

      - *MySharedComponents*

When i try to move my shared components as one Project and try to install it in  other project like below structure. This gives compilation syntax error.

- **Feature** (My shared component project)

  - Src

    - Components

      - *MySharedComponents*
- **Project**

  - node_modules

    - Feature
  - Zoo

    - Src
    - Components

GIT Repo : https://github.com/andiappan-ar/babelIssue.git

[image]

I installed my shared project using below command

```
> npm install --save ../../feature
```

My Zoo Project server.webpack.config.js below

```
const path = require('path');
const env = require('@babel/preset-env');
const reactApp = require('babel-preset-react-app');
// Webpack build configuration to build the SSR bundle.
// Invoked by build:server.

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './server.js'),
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    filename: '../build/server.bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'this',
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: false,
            presets: [env, reactApp],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: 'html-loader' },
      },
      {
        // anything not JS or HTML, we load as a URL
        // this makes static image imports work with SSR
        test: /\.(?!js|mjs|jsx|html|graphql$)[^.]+$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        // anything in node_modules that isn't js,
        // we load as null - e.g. imported css from a module,
        // that is not needed for SSR
        test: /\.(?!js|mjs|jsx|html|graphql$)[^.]+$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'null-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My Zoo project package.json below

```
{
  "name": "jss-sample-react",
  "description": "Application utilizing Sitecore JavaScript Services and React (create-react-app).",
  "version": "11.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "appName": "SafariZoo",
    "rootPlaceholders": [
      "jss-main"
    ],
    "sitecoreDistPath": "/dist/SafariZoo",
    "sitecoreConfigPath": "/App_Config/Include/zzz",
    "graphQLEndpointPath": "/api/SafariZoo",
    "language": "en"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.1",
    "npm": ">=5.6.0",
    "yarn": "yarn is not supported, please use npm"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Sitecore Corporation",
    "url": "https://jss.sitecore.net"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sitecore/jss.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sitecore/jss/issues"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react": "^11.0.2",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-tracking": "^11.0.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "feature": "../../feature",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "~1.3.12",
    "apollo-client": "~2.4.8",
    "apollo-link": "~1.2.6",
    "apollo-link-batch-http": "~1.2.6",
    "apollo-link-http": "~1.5.9",
    "apollo-link-persisted-queries": "~0.2.2",
    "axios": "~0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "graphql": "~14.0.2",
    "graphql-tag": "~2.10.0",
    "i18next": "~13.1.2",
    "i18next-fetch-backend": "~2.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "~2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "~16.7.0",
    "react-apollo": "~2.3.3",
    "react-dom": "~16.7.0",
    "react-helmet": "~5.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "~9.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "~4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "serialize-javascript": "~1.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "~7.0.0",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli": "^11.0.2",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-dev-tools": "^11.0.2",
    "@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-manifest": "^11.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "~7.0.0",
    "chalk": "~2.4.2",
    "chokidar": "~2.0.4",
    "cross-env": "~5.2.0",
    "graphql.macro": "~1.0.2",
    "html-loader": "~0.5.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.19.1",
    "npm-run-all": "~4.1.5",
    "null-loader": "~0.1.1",
    "url-loader": "~1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "~3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "jss": "jss",
    "start": "npm-run-all --serial bootstrap:disconnected --parallel start:react start:proxy start:watch-components",
    "start:connected": "scjss-verify-setup && npm-run-all --serial bootstrap:connected start:react start:watch-components",
    "build": "npm-run-all --serial bootstrap:connected build:client build:server",
    "scaffold": "node scripts/scaffold-component.js",
    "start:react": "react-scripts start",
    "start:proxy": "node scripts/disconnected-mode-proxy.js",
    "start:watch-components": "node scripts/generate-component-factory.js --watch",
    "build:client": "cross-env-shell PUBLIC_URL=$npm_package_config_sitecoreDistPath \"react-scripts build\"",
    "build:server": "cross-env-shell NODE_ENV=production \"webpack --config server/server.webpack.config.js\"",
    "bootstrap:connected": "node scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "bootstrap:disconnected": "node scripts/bootstrap.js --disconnected",
    "graphql:update": "node -r babel-register ./scripts/update-graphql-fragment-data.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I tried below options but nothing works,

1. Instead of manually install my shared project, i have  used lerna that also causing the same issue.
2. Currently my project doesnt have ".babelrc" file  all my babel-presets in webpackconfig itself. Even i introduce babelrc file in both project doesnt solve the issue.
3. I have cross across many git links they are saying to add presets in multiple way. but nothing work out. 
   The related Issue seems still open https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5100.

**How to solve this issue ?** or **how i can share my component to multiple project with out this babel issue ?**

Comment: Have you tried adding backticks around the h3 element so that subheading = `<h3..../h3>` or just moving the <h3> to the same line as subheading =    I'm sure I've seen similar issues when I've tried to assign multiple lines but didn't use the right quote, back tick or { :)

Comment: In the babel-loader config in your webpack configuration, you explicitly exclude everything in node_modules from being processed with Babel. You will have to adjust the exclude expression to allow transpiration of your Feature component.

Comment: @PatrickHund i tried   exclude: [/node_modules/],include:[/node_modules\/feature/], same issue coming.

Comment: @SteveB i had tried yours but same issue coming. This issue not related to syntax actually this same code is working when component under the same project. only fails when its come from node_modules.

Comment: Did U solve this? I have the same issue but using CRA.